# jQuery noConflict not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following peice of JavaScript which is going to be referenced from a client's website. It uses jQuery 1.5 so my problem is what if the client already has an instance of jQuery loaded? Or an alternative JavaScript library?

I am using noConflict() to try and work around this but it just doesn't seem to work and I can't work out why. Any help is appreciated

The main issue is that I get an error returned telling me that jQueryMH is undefined, but I am clearly defining it before i even set the interval on the keepAlive function.

```
var head    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script  = document.createElement('script');
script.src  = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                                var jQueryMH = jQuery.noConflict(true);
                                                setInterval(keepAlive(), 5000);
                                            };
head.appendChild(script);
function keepAlive() {
    var mhProtocol      = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://");
    var randomNumber    = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    var mhVisitorId     = document.cookie.match('mhVisitorId=(.*?)(;|$)');
    var urlParamString  = "";
    if(mhVisitorId) { 
        urlParamString = "&mhVisitorId=" + encodeURIComponent(mhVisitorId[1]); 
    }
    var mhUrl = "www.urlishere.com";
    //var jQueryMH = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQueryMH.ajax({
        url: mhUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}
```

Other than this, i have tried setting the noConflict() within the function itself and this works and allows me to reference jQueryMH, but then we have the following problem, probably because it is setting noConflict each time the functions runs (every 5s)

The test page I have set up which externally includes this JS Script already has jQuery 1.8 loaded and then it loads the above script afterwards. So because of my noConflict, i would expect jQueryMH.fn.jquery to return 1.5.0 and jQuery.fn.jquery to return 1.8; however they both return 1.5.0 which means my noConflict is not working as jQuery does not stay as the version 1.8 library already loaded on to the clients website.

Comment: `setInterval(keepAlive(), 5000);` -> `setInterval(function(){keepAlive(jQueryMH);}, 5000);` and `function keepAlive() {` ->
 `function keepAlive(jQueryMH) {`

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to `noconflict` the *first* version of jQuery before the second version can be loaded, otherwise the second will just overwrite the first.

Apart from that, your undefined variable problem is caused because you're calling `.noconflict` within a function and assigning jQuery to an alternate variable that is only in scope *within that function*.

I think you'll need to first do:

```
var origjQuery = jQuery.noconflict();
```

then load the new jQuery as you do above, then `noconflict` that:

```
var jQueryMH = jQuery.noconflict();
```

and then restore the original jQuery:

```
var jQuery = origjQuery.noconflict();
```

Do all of the above in global scope.

Comment: I don't know whether the client will have a jQuery library loaded, obviously I could check the type of the jQuery variable but I also can't modify their setup, for example if they have 1.8 included on their page and they have some 1.8.x only plugins, I need to make sure nothing on their website is modified.

Comment: After i have included the external JS file on to my test page (which already has 1.8 loaded), and i then output the version of jQuery/$ it shows 1.8, in my external JS script i output the version of jQueryMH and it shows 1.5, seems to be fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I built a custom build of jQuery, modifying the line of code where jQuery is assigned to the global variable.

Specifically, I transformed that line of code from:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

to

```
window.myCustomJquery = jQuery;
```

In this way, even if in the page contains jQuery script, I can inject my custom build of jQuery without any problems, and without the need to seal/freeze the actual global jQuery or without using .noConflict(), both solutions that were causing the problems above.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem when injecting a script on any other host.

As Alnitak stated, `noConflict` works if you load jQuery first and then you are overwriting the `$` variable, not the other way around.

The workaround I managed to build uses the [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) and [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) methods from ECMAScript 5.

The thing is to copy the variables you want to overwrite on the existing site (such as `$`) into an object that you will eventually freeze.
By freezing that object before you rewrite the variable (before loading jQuery) you ensure that a copy of the original variables (in your case `$`) would be stored in your object and that they cannot be altered in any way by any other script.
After loading your desired libs, you can just copy the object properties that you've frozen back into the global object, leaving the host environment intact.
Here's a sample code to make things clearer :

```
var aux = {'jQuery' : window.jQuery};
if(Object.freeze)
    // prevent anyone from deleting any of the `aux` props
    Object.freeze(aux);
if(Object.seal)
    // prevent anyone from altering the initial jQuery
    // this is necessary because `aux.jQuery` is a copy by reference of the
    // window.jQuery, thus any modification in the global jQuery object
    // would be reflected in our jQuery copy
    Object.seal(aux.jQuery);

var head    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script  = document.createElement('script');
script.src  = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var jQueryMH = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // restore the initial jquery
    window.jQuery = aux.jQuery;
    alert(jQuery === jQueryMH);
};
```

And, of course you can extend the functionality and use it for any other libs that you use:

```
var __globalLibs = {},
    libsThatYouWantToPreserve = '$ jQuery otherLib'.split(' '),
    key;

for(var i=0,l=libsThatYouWantToPreserve.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        key = libsThatYouWantToPreserve[i];
        // copy the contents of the global variable into your object
        __globalLibs[key] = window[key];
        if(Object.seal)
            Object.seal(__globalLibs[key]);
    }

if(Object.freeze)
    Object.freeze(__globalLibs);

// load jquery and all the other libs

// make copies of your update libs

var jQueryMH = jQuery;

// and then restore the initial variables to the global context
 for(var i=0,l=libsThatYouWantToPreserve.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        key = libsThatYouWantToPreserve[i];
        // copy the contents of the global variable into your object
        window[key] = __globalLibs[key];
    }

// after that, you can just delete your object
delete window.__globalLibs;
```

The only downside is that is not supported by IE8 and lower.
Hope this helps!

P.S. : You should probably change `setInterval(keepAlive(), 5000);` to `setInterval(keepAlive, 5000);`, because your construction means to repeat the evaluation of the `keepAlive` **return value** (which is `undefined`) - and not the function itself - every 5 seconds.

Comment: What if the jQuery that is already in the page executes something (like a jQuery plugin) between the freeze/seal and the end of the loading of new jQuery?
If the executed jQuery plugin  manage its state, it will be not possibile to modify this state, so an inconsistent state/situation will be created, will not it?